# partial derivatives of multivariable function

Tags: derivatives, math

Looking to verify whether the following formulation is correct. Suppose we have the following function, relationships:

$$y=f(x)$$
$$x=g(a,b)$$
$$y=f[g(a,b)]$$

Is the below correct (including notation)?
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial b}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial b}$$

In words, the total derivative of the composite function $y$ with respect to $x$ is the sum of the partial derivatives of $y$ with respect to $a$ and $b$

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/14%3A_Differentiation_of_Functions_of_Several_Variables/14.5%3A_The_Chain_Rule_for_Multivariable_Functions

Answer (score 2):

No, this is in general not true. For example, consider
\begin{align*}
y(x)&:=x,\\
x(a,b):&=a+b. 
\end{align*}
Then we have 
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=1$$
but 
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial b}=2. $$